# How to generate a 64 bit tag for tuples during compilation?

Tags: garbage-collection, compiler-construction, x86-64

So, I am working on a compiler and I am following a textbook.

Here are some definitions

The `collect(n)` form runs the garbage collector, requesting that it make sure
that there are n bytes ready to be allocated.

The `allocate(n,type)` form obtains memory for n elements (and space at the front for
the 64-bit tag), but the elements are not initialized.

The `global_value(name)` form reads the value of a global variable, such as
free_ptr.

heres is what the selection instruction pass would generate:

```
lhs = allocate(len, TupleType([type, ... ]));
->
movq free_ptr(%rip), %r11
addq 8(len + 1), free_ptr(%rip)
movq $tag, 0(%r11)
movq %r11, lhs′
```

here is the part of the example thats relevant:

```
alloc2 = (allocate 1 (Vector Integer));
->
movq free_ptr(%rip), %r11
addq $16, free_ptr(%rip)
movq $3, 0(%r11)
movq %r11, alloc2
```

Above `$3` is the tag. but the book also says:
`We recommend using the bitwise-or operator | and the shift-left operator « to compute the tag during compilation.` How is `3` here the tag?

So im not sure how im suppose to generate the tag which is  64 bits.

Heres a quote to give some background for tags which are used for the garbage collector.

```
The problem of distinguishing between pointers and other kinds of data also
arises inside each tuple on the heap. We solve this problem by attaching a tag, an
extra 64 bits, to each tuple.
```